# Spring 4.0.0 + Eclipse + Maven + WAS8.0 = ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.asm.commons.EmptyVisitor

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I followed http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/creating-a-spring-mvc-project-using-maven-and-eclipse-in-one-minute to get a basic Spring MVC skeleton set up. That worked right out of the box running on WAS8.0. We use Spring 4.0.0.RELEASE here, so I went into the pom.xml and changed the spring version to 4.0.0.RELEASE, and now the app no longer works. Browsing to the webpage gives

`Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet`

And examining the error in the Eclipse console: http://fpaste.org/107837/07216414/

My current pom.xml (only file that has changed from the tutorial) http://fpaste.org/107880/02080310/

The only change made was changing the spring.version to 4.0.0.RELEASE.

Contents of /WEB-INF/lib

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
```

Output of `mvn dependency:tree`:

```
com.redacted.test:Spring4MVCTest2:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
+- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
|  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
|  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:test
+- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:provided
\- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:provided
```

http://fpaste.org/107879/08026714/

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Make sure that you don't have old classes/jars left in your deployment (wouldn't be the first that web sphere left some jars behind while redeploying). Also please add the stack trace and pom to your post, don't let people click around the internet to find all related information. And please add the output of `mvn dependency:tree` and the content of the `WEB-INF\lib` directory.

Comment: I left those as links because they are kind of lengthy and don't play well with markdown.

Comment: Is that the full content? I miss at least `spring-beans.jar` and `spring-orm.jar`. Remove the `<type>` tag from the dependencies, shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Updated. Still no dice

Comment: For some reason some of the jars aren't being included in your WEB-INF/lib. I'm missing `spring-beans`, `spring-orm`, `spring-jdbc` and `spring-td`.

Comment: You're right. Not entirely sure why they're not being included.

Comment: Try running maven with -X (generates a lot of output) and see to figure out why those aren't included. `mvn clean install -X` should do the trick. I assume you are using maven to build your artifacts!

Comment: I think you need to exclude javax.servlet explicitly from your spring-core dependency.

Comment: Also try to add spring-library directly, just to check. `org.springframework.spring-library`